# avoid column slicing array for calculations

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
Xs = np.array([[1,3,3,4,5,7], [2,4,5,1,1,6], [5,5,6,4,3,2]]).T
groupIDs = np.array([10,10,20,20,30,30])
p = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0])
_,idx,tags = np.unique(groupIDs, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)
print(Xs)
[[1 2 5]
 [3 4 5]
 [3 5 6]
 [4 1 4]
 [5 1 3]
 [7 6 2]]
```

I am trying to create a new table with the sum of products between `p` and `X` per group, *for each column*. The only way I can think to make this work is

```
new = np.empty((6,3))
for i in range(3):
    new[:,i] = np.add.reduceat((p * Xs[:,i]),idx)[tags] 
print(new)
[[ 2.    3.    5.  ]
 [ 2.    3.    5.  ]
 [ 3.75  2.    4.5 ]
 [ 3.75  2.    4.5 ]
 [ 5.    1.    3.  ]
 [ 5.    1.    3.  ]]
```

I am straggling to tune my mind into thinking 'vector-wise' to make it work (hopefully) faster for my large dataset consisting of thousands of xs by avoiding the loop. Any suggestions please.

Comment: maybe un-transpose `Xs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
Xs = np.array([[1,3,3,4,5,7], [2,4,5,1,1,6], [5,5,6,4,3,2]])
groupIDs = np.array([10,10,20,20,30,30])
p = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0])
_,idx,tags = np.unique(groupIDs, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)

print np.add.reduceat((p*Xs).T, idx)[tags]
```

No need to use a `for`. It is sufficient to transpose some matrix, check the last line.

I remove the transpose in the declaration of `Xs`. But if you really need it, you'll have to add one in the last line (`(p*Xs.T).T`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the `.T` in my initial declaration of Xs just to make it easier to create a data frame with n = 6 and no Xs = 3, so the starting point should be an 6x3 `array`. Hence, my question is -and it's an honest one- aren't two transformations going to be more expensive than the `for` loop ?

Comment: The transformation is not done in the memory so it is not more expansive to use two more `.T`. After a quick check, my proposal runs 3 times faster than your original one (on your example)

Comment: With a set of dummies as Xs, if I redefined them as `sparse.csr_matrix(Xs)`, could this code be amendable so as to do the multiplication of p * X only for the non-zero values of Xs ? (for my actual set, it's currently taking me ~40 secs per iteration to execute the part of my script discussed here..)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option without `np.unique` (assume same groupIDs have been sorted together):

```
def diff():
    idx = np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(np.diff(groupIDs))+1))
    inv = np.repeat(pd.np.arange(idx.size), np.diff(np.concatenate((idx, [groupIDs.size]))))
    return np.add.reduceat((Xs.T*p), idx, axis=1).T[inv]

diff()
#array([[ 2.  ,  3.  ,  5.  ],
#       [ 2.  ,  3.  ,  5.  ],
#       [ 3.75,  2.  ,  4.5 ],
#       [ 3.75,  2.  ,  4.5 ],
#       [ 5.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ],
#       [ 5.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ]])
```